# How do I ignore a single file in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

Here's the content of file *.gitignore* (located in the project's main folder)

#### File */Volumes/drive2/my-project/.gitignore*

```
.project

/config/file-im-trying-to-ignore.txt
config/file-im-trying-to-ignore.txt
file-im-trying-to-ignore.txt
```

These are the steps I used when making the changes:

- edit *.gitignore*
- commit
- edit file-I'm-trying-to-ignore.txt

What am I doing wrong?

I've committed my repository after making changes to *.gitignore* and then made changes to *file-I'm-trying-to-ignore.txt*

I used these two sites as reference:

- *[.gitignore file - ignoring files in Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20ignore,directory%20as%20an%20ignored%20file)*
- *[Ignoring Files and Directories in Git (.gitignore)](https://linuxize.com/post/gitignore-ignoring-files-in-git/)*

Comment: May be a long shot, but try investigating encoding of a file - I had trouble for long time with this - it simply did not work as it should. It turned out I had some wild encoding (othher than any UTF or Unicode), which was not correctly understood by git. Make sure it is set to UTF-8

Comment: Does [this answer](/a/36713835/4265352) help?

Comment: @axiac that fixed it for me. Can you please leave that as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file already indexed? .gitignore affects only files that are not indexed by Git (staged or committed).

If your file just staged and never committed before - you should unstage file with `git reset HEAD your_file`. [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Or, if your file was committed previously, thus indexed in Git, you should remove it from index with `git rm --cached your_file`, then commit. Then .gitignore takes effect. [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm). Clean the file from .gitignore while removing it from cache, then add it back there.

Comment: Git reset might be used in both cases with appropriate flag (`--soft` `--medium` or `--hard`)

Comment: Well, probably. Have not used it this way, but as I remember, it will reset the whole commit, and from the latest back, not the single file. Flags just specify what changes to keep or delete in the working tree.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is already committed and pushed to your repository, you must *untrack* the file where you will add to `.gitignore`, and then `.gitignore` only works on **untracked** files. To untrack files, run following command:

```
# Untrack all files
git rm -r --cache

# Untrack one specific file
git rm --cache filename.txt
```

After *untracking* the file, you can add (`git add .`), commit (`git commit -m ".gitignore now ignores the file"`) and push (`git push`) it to your repository.

Answer (score -1):

Try using *[git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)* to untrack the file.

Comment: do you have a sample command I can use? I haven't used git reset in that context previously. Thank you.